# When creating a WordPress page, a "-2" suffix is added to new pages' permalinks

Tags: permalinks, slug

I have noticed after deleting an original page in WordPress with lets say a permalink of `your_domain.com/contact/` and then trying to recreate the same page with the same name/slug, my WP is generating a "*-2*" at the end of the link, like: `your_domain.com/contact-2/`.

I don't understand why, since the original page was deleted. Why is WordPress treating new pages as if the original still exists? How to I clean WP caches, if such a thing even exists?
Thank you ahead of time for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 6):

Delete the page permanently from the Trash.

As long as it lives in the Trash, the post exists with [status](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) `'trash'`.